# Drupal ccavenue payment error -Illegal access detected

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce, ccavenue

I am new in drupal, and I don't have much knowledge about it. 
I have enabled **ccavenue payment module with commerce** in my drupal system, and created and donation page. If I am using another "Example payment", It's working without any issue.

But when I try to do payment with ccavenue, On repsonse page, It givin me error message **"Security Error. Illegal access detected. We will store your IP address".**

Is I missing something?

Comment: This question belongs to the [Drupal Stack](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

- You should give the URL from which you're sending the request to ccavenue and then they will add it to the white list URLs and you could see it in your merchant console account. ccavenue will not accept any requests from an unknown URL.
- Also did you check the merchant ID, accept token & encryption key correct?

Hope this information helps.